# Atualizar itens do Spinner em tempo de execução

Tags: android, sqlite

Tenho um spinner que retorna as cidades salvas no meu BD, quando esta cidade não existe, permito cadastrar a mesma, e após cadastrar e salvar, faço com que feche a activity de cadastro de cidade e retorne para a anterior que seria a activity que contem o spinner, só que essa cidade que acabou de ser salva, não aparece no meu spinner, tenho que sair do app e voltar nele de novo para que possa atualizar essa informação.
Como faço para atualizar os dados do spinner em tempo de execução, ou seja assim que retorno para a activity que contem o spinner?
Segue o meu spinner:

```
List<String> labels = ds.getAllLabels();

spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,labels);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Já tentou `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: Já sim, mas não consegui implementar no meu projeto, teria algum exemplo?

Comment: Tente implementar o onActivityResult, nele coloque o metodo que refaz a busca de cidades e da notifyDataSetChanged no adapter.